# Run Database Stored RegEx against DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, database, screen-scraping

I have a question about how to approach a certain scenario before I get halfway through it and figure out it was not the best option.

I work for a large company that has a team that creates tools for the team mates to use that aren’t official enterprise tools. We have no access to the database directly, just access to an internal server to store our files to run and be able to access the main site with javascript etc (same domain).

What I am working on is a tool that has a ton of options in it that allow you to select that I will call “data points” on a page.

There are things like “Account status, Balance, Name, Phone number, email etc” and have it save those to an excel sheet.

So you input account numbers, choose what you need and then using IE Objects it navigates to the page and scrapes data you request.

**My question is as follows..**

I want to make the scraping part pretty Dynamic in the way it works. I want to be able to add new datapoints on the fly.

My goal or idea is so store the regular expression needed to get the specific piece of data in the table with the “data point option”.

If I choose “Name” it knows the expression for name in the database to run again the DOM.
What would be the best way about creating that type of function in Javascript / Jquery?
I need to pass a Regex to a function, have it run against the DOM and then return the result.

I have a feeling that there will be things that require more than 1 step to get the information etc.

I am just trying to think of the best way to approach it without having to hardcode 200+ expressions into the file as the page may get updated and need to be changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you give a sample for the regex and the dom element structure

Comment: That's the thing, I haven't got that far ahead yet. At the point i am at; I have the DOM in a variable and then a way to loop through the database and pull expressions based on the choice of the user. In general lets say I targeted the stackoverflow home page. I would want to get the persons name that is logged in, the number of features jobs and something else. I some how need to create a dynamic function or multiple where I can say this piece of data will need to run through function A and B to get the result. Just cant think of the best way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

IRobotSoft scraper may be the tool you are looking for.  Check this forum and see if questions are similar to what you are doing: http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?board=newcomer.  It is free.

What it uses is not regular expression but a language called HTQL, which may be more suitable for extracting web pages.  It also supports regular expression, but not as the main language.

It organizes all your actions well with a visual interface, so you can dynamically compose actions or tasks for changing needs.